# Create backup image of running Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, images

On Windows there is software like Acronis True Image that can create full backup images of a currently running system. Is there any alternative on Ubuntu for doing that?

Requirements:

- still supported / maintained (e.g. not the case for systemback)
- is able to make a consistent backup of a **running** system (e.g. live CDs like clonezilla are not what I am looking for)

Thanks for any hint on this!

Comment: What is your use case scenario? Is this just to make a backup? Backing up running systems is inherently inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tar`.  Tar is free and can be used on a running system to both backup and restore. I have used it to successfully restore to a running (but unstable) system. For Ubuntu, there is a very nice tutorial [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) on how to use it to backup and restore in many different scenarios.

Here is an example of creating a full backup:

```
tar -cpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/tmp --one-file-system /
```

`-cpzf` create a new zipped tarball and preserve all file permissions

`--one-file-system` do not backup mount points and non-file dirs like /dev

To improve archive speed, you can pipe the output of tar through `pigz` which will use all your cores in parallel to zip the file. You might need to install pigz using `apt-get`.

Here is an example of creating a full backup using pigz:

```
tar -cpf - --exclude=/tmp --one-file-system / | pigz > /path/to/backup.tar.gz
```

To restore, run this while logged in as root to a running system:

```
cd /
tar -xpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz
```

To restore from livecd:

```
cd /media/ubuntu/your_old_drive
tar -xpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz --numeric-owner
```

`--numeric-owner` restores file ownership without translating the user id (very important when restoring from a live cd)